# Handling sheet changes in the Google Sheets API

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to handle Spreadsheet changes for updating local version of data, and got some troubles:

- Google Sheets API does not have any request for checking last modified time or file version. (Correct me, if i mistake)
- Google need some time to handle changes and update version metadata of the file.

For example:

File is in version 10.

1. Sending BatchUpdateRequest with some data
2. By the end of the previous request checking file version by DriveAPI Files.Get request with field "version" and get old version 10

If wait about 15 seconds this request returns correct data, but it's not a solution because data updates every minute for each spreadsheet, so, it will spends a lot more time.

To overcome these problems i have realized logic with local calculating of Spreadsheet version, and comparing it after uploading: if online version > local version spreadsheet will be reload. But it creates new problem:

If make changes to Spreadsheet from several computers at a few moment, local version on all computers will be increased, but Google concats this changes into one version. So, for correct working it must be oldversionnubmer + countOfComputersThatMakesChanges but in fact it is oldVersionNumber + 1. Thus no one will get actual spreadsheet data because online version will not be higher than local.

In this way i have a question: **How can I updates spreadsheets on changing data from another source?**

GoogleSpreadsheetsVersions filling like that:

```
var versions = Instance.GoogleSpreadsheetsVersions;

    if (!versions.ContainsKey(newTable.SpreadsheetId)) {
                        var request = GoogleSpreadsheetsServiceDecorator.Instance.DriveService.Files.Get(newTable.SpreadsheetId);
                        request.Fields = "version";
                        var response = request.Execute();
                        versions.Add(newTable.SpreadsheetId, response.Version);
                    }
```

version comparison itself:

```
            var newInfo = new Dictionary<string, long?>();
            foreach (var info in GoogleSpreadsheetsVersions)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Gets file version
                    var request = GoogleSpreadsheetsServiceDecorator.Instance.DriveService.Files.Get(info.Key);
                    request.Fields = "version";
                    var response = request.Execute();

                    // local version < actual google version
                    if (info.Value < response.Version)
                    {
                        // setting flag of reloading for each sheet from this file
                        foreach (var t in GoogleSpreadsheets.Where(sheet => sheet.SpreadsheetId == info.Key))
                            t.IsLoadRequestRequired = true;
                    }
                    //Refreshing local versions
                    newInfo.Add(info.Key, response.Version);
                }
                catch (Exception e) when (e.Message.Contains("File not found"))
                {
                    newInfo.Add(info.Key, null);
                }
            }
            GoogleSpreadsheetsVersions = newInfo;
```

P.S.:

- version field description from Google guide:
  A monotonically increasing version number for the file. This reflects every change made to the file on the server, even those not visible to the user.
- Local class of Spreadsheet in code means data of one sheet in Google. So, if one Google spreadsheet contains 10 sheets it will be 10 spreadsheets in programm.
- May be helpful [DriveAPI.Files.Get request fileds](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files?hl=en)

Comment: I think that a best solution for what you are trying to do would be to use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script). With that you can have a [trigger function that executes on edit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite). Would you be ok with an Apps Script solution?